# Function composition, invertibility, domain of functions.

Tags: functions

Finding the domain is easy; the rest I don't understand how to do.

Let $f(x)=x-6\sqrt[]{x}+9$. Find the domain of $f$. Show that $(f \circ f)(x) = x$ for $x \in [0, 9]$. Is $f$ invertible with $f^{-1}=f$?

Comment: Hint: $f(x)=(\sqrt{x}-3)^2$ then $(f \circ f)(x)=\cdots\;$.

Comment: **Hint 2**: If $(f \circ f)(x) = x$ then $f$ is invertible with $f^{-1}=f$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{equation}
(f∘f)(x)=(\sqrt{x-6\sqrt x +9}-3)^2\\=x-6\sqrt x +9+9-6\sqrt{x-6\sqrt x +9}\\=x-6\sqrt x +18-6\sqrt{(\sqrt{x}-3)^2}\\=x-6\sqrt x +18-6|\sqrt x-3|
\end{equation}

For $x\in [0,9]$, $\sqrt x-3$ is negative so we can write:

\begin{equation}
x-6\sqrt x +18-6|\sqrt x-3|\\=x-6\sqrt x +18-6[-(\sqrt x-3)]\\=x-6\sqrt x +18+6\sqrt x-18\\=x 
\end{equation}

We can say that $f$ is invertible with $f^{-1}=f$ when $x\in [0,9]$.